# Popup when opening files in Telegram Desktop snap

Tags: files, snap, telegram

I have a super weird question. Whenever I try to open a file or try to show a file by clicking on the message in Telegram Desktop, this popup shows up:

[image: I always have to click 'Yes', which is super annoying 'cause i open so many files.]

I always have to click 'Yes', which is super annoying 'cause I open so many files.

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Telegram Desktop version 1.4.3.

Does anyone know how to resolve that and give permanent permission?

Comment: i've just figured out how to allow telegram to store files without asking using this command: sudo snap op  telegram-desktop:home

is there a way that opening files is also possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've just figured out how to allow telegram to store files without asking using this command:

```
sudo snap connect telegram-desktop:home
```

Comment: It would be great if you or anyone could add some background. I read `snap help connect` to find `The connect command connects a plug to a slot.` yeah, sure, good to know :-/ What is `home` above? The home directory or some snap-secret curse?