# How to always allow Firefox to open files

Tags: firefox, snap

I am quite new to Ubuntu and I was wondering how I could disable or remove the dialog that says '**Allow opening file**':

[image: Allow opening file]

**Answer:**

For anyone facing a problem with Firefox uninstall firefox and reinstall from the terminal like so `sudo apt install firefox` and everything should be working fine as it does with mine. Don't know why this is but it is a solution

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate I searched everywhere couldn't find one

Comment: How do I fix this

Comment: You need to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098992/480481). That one is about `telegram-desktop` snap, yours about `firefox` snap. So you need to run the same command with `firefox` in place of `telegram-desktop`.

Comment: I think I got it

Comment: I've tried and now I give up

Comment: You try to open a file named `templerun.zip`, I have the impression you need to open this file with an archive manger rather than with firefox.

Comment: Late to the show, but reading `snap help connect` I feel the snap devs have fun mocking users. And no, I am not a newbie, using Linux for 30 years now, but this one is abysmal.